# how to detect location change in an angular directive?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an angular directive `detectFocus` as :

```
app.directive("detectFocus", function ($focusTest, $location, $rootScope) {
return {
    restrict: "A",
    scope: {
        onFocus: '&onFocus',
        onBlur: '&onBlur',
    },
    link: function (scope, elem) {
        $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function (event, newUrl, oldUrl) {
            return;
        });

        elem.on("focus", function () { console.log("focus");
            scope.onFocus();
            $focusTest.setFocusOnBlur(true);
        });

        elem.on("blur", function () {  console.log("blur");
            scope.onBlur();
            if($focusTest.getFocusOnBlur())
                elem[0].focus();
        });
    }
}
```

});

this directive check two event focus and blur, so is there any way to check location change from this directive.

Comment: You may try this: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#$locationChangeSuccess

Comment: which router are you using? They have routeChange events

Comment: ui-router/..............

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try binding a listener on Angulars built in `$locationChangeSuccess` event. This event is fired every time your app has finished changing a location.

Your link function could look somehow like this.

```
link: function($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function (event, newUrl, oldUrl) {
     console.log('Changed from ', oldUrl, ' to ', newUrl);
  });
}
```

Comment: your code is detecting the changes of location. but once my focus function of the directive is running it is not working. i have editted the question.please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a watch on `$location.path()`

```
myModule.directive('highlighttab', ['$location', function(location) {

    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            var elementPath = $attrs.href.substring(1);
            $scope.$location = location;
            $scope.$watch('$location.path()', function(locationPath) {
                (elementPath === locationPath) ? $element.addClass("current") : $element.removeClass("current");
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

adding watch variable is not much a recomented process since it will increase the load of the application. Instead you can use the `$locationChangeSuccess` event in angular js.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular-route.min.js"></script>

<script>
    var app = angular.module('routeApp', ['ngRoute']);

    app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/addStudent', {
                template: '<div>Add Student</div>',
                controller: 'addStudentController'
            })
            .when('/viewStudent', {
                template: '<div>View Student</div>',
                controller: 'viewStudentController'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
    }]);

    app.directive('activeLink', ['$location', function (location) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {
                var clazz = attrs.activeLink;
                var path = attrs.href;
                path = path.substring(1); //hack because path does bot return including hashbang
                scope.location = location;
                scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function () {
                    console.log('$locationChangeSuccess changed!', new Date());
                });
            }

        };

     }]);

    app.controller('addStudentController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.message = "This is message from add student controller";

    });

    app.controller('viewStudentController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.message = "This is message from view student controller";
    });

    app.controller('pageController', function ($scope, $location) {
        $scope.GoTo = function (URl) {
            $location.path('/' + URl);
        };
    });
</script>


<body ng-app="routeApp" ng-controller="pageController">
    <h2>Sample Application</h2>

    <a href="#/addStudent" active-link="active">Add Student</a>
    <a href="#/viewStudent" active-link="active">View Student</a>
    <a href="#" active-link="active">home</a>


    <div ng-view></div>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this way. Using $watch can lead to performance issues. Since there's native Angular way for this you should stick to that. So `$location.$locationChangeSuccess()` should be the proper way.

Answer (score 0):

inject $rootScope and use it like this :

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(evt, to, params) {
    //do your stuff here
}
```

Furthermore if you use `elem.on('focus/blur')` you must call `scope.$apply()` in the even callback if you want angular to detect the changes.